# Android foreground service kills after sometime

Tags: android, android-service

I am working on a Heart Rate Monitor device which retrieves data every second. To continuously fetch data in background, I am using foreground service.

The issue is whether the app is in Background or killed from recent, after few minutes or an hour, it automatically gets killed. And when I tried to find the root cause, I found following logs in the logcat:

```
D/RestartProcessManager: updateSelf :  com.app.abc, size : 30
D/RestartProcessManager: com.app.abc got score 74.0204410100582 in DayDuration for duration : 820920
D/RestartProcessManager: com.app.abc got score 100.0 in DayLRU for LRU diff : 23956652
D/RestartProcessManager: com.app.abc got score 87.5 in DayLaunchTimes for launch times : 7
D/RestartProcessManager: com.app.abc : X : 3740.3846153846152, Y : 2966.031866654173, Z : 5797.203585179621
I/ActivityManager: Killing 9110:com.app.abc/u0a1968 (adj 100): [BgDetect][RNK] kill com.app.abc (uid 11968) usage 4
D/ActivityManager: Process com.app.abc has 2 services
W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.app.abc/com.app.abc.service.HeartRateService in 1000ms
W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.app.abc/com.app.abc.base.control.manage.BluetoothLeService in 11000ms
```

Mobile device in which I was testing is:
One Plus 3T with OS version 8.0.0.

What could be the possible solution to prevent crashing this service?

============UPDATE

I found following logs for service restart issue:

```
W/ActivityManager: Unable to launch app com.app.abc/11968 for service Intent { cmp=com.app.abc/com.app.abc.base.control.manage.BluetoothLeService }: process is bad
D/NotificationListener: onNotificationRemoved# hash: 102296955 sbn: StatusBarNotification(pkg=android user=UserHandle{0} id=40 tag=null key=0|android|40|null|1000: Notification(channel=FOREGROUND_SERVICE pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x2 color=0xff607d8b vis=PRIVATE))
```

Comment: Have you started your service as _Sticky_ ?

Comment: Yes. I am using START_STICKY

Comment: It means it will be continue to run even if killed or remove from recent app. How are you starting your service ?

Comment: The issue is I can see scheduling restarting service after xxxms but actually it is not restarted.

Comment: Do you want to restart or not ?

Comment: As I am doing Bluetooth related operations I don't want my service to stop. If it stops then I will loose my connection with the Bluetooth device. @Piyush

Comment: If your service is sticky then it will be restarted if you remove from recent apps.

Comment: Please find the updated logs. @Piyush

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/806)

Comment: Thank you. I guess it's the issue with device brand and specific OS version.

Comment: Yes, It is !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen only on your One Plus 3T?
If you dont know you better run same test on another device because some device problems are brand specific

Comment: I guess it's an issue with device brand as I tried with Samsung S6(OS v8.1) and faced this issue once. And on OnePlus3T, I am continuously facing this issue. I didn't face this issue on Xiomi redmi device(OS v9.0) and Lenovo(OS v8.0.0).